# iOS: Do I need to unregister in a navigation controller from keyboard events every time the view disappears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, nsnotifications

I'm working on my embedded table views. They should scroll up when the keyboard hides some textfields. But I have several view controllers in my navigation view controller with this behaviour. So far my code registration and unregistration code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

But if I'm showing the keyboard in let's say view controller number 3 in my navigation controller, the keyboardWasShown method is called three times. Doesn't this matter or do I need to unregister everytime the viewWillDisappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `[self registerForKeyboardNotifications];` to `viewDidAppear` and unregister in `viewDidDisappear`.

By registering in `viewDidLoad` and unregistering in `dealloc`, especially within a navigation controller, the notification will fire once for every view controller on the navigation stack.  You only need to call it for the currently visible view.

Alternatively, you could subclass the navigation controller and have it call a method on its currently visible controller.  Then you don't have to do all this registering and unregistering.  Just register once in a nav controller subclass and have that class pass the message along to the proper view controller.

Comment: Ok and this isn't any performance issue or anything? I'm sorry still new to iOS :-)

Comment: I updated my answer.  I'd let the nav controller handle the notifications.  Registering and unregistering in each view controller might very slightly effect performance... but not as much as having several view controllers all respond to the notification when only one of them needs to.

Comment: Hmm I actually don't really understand how I would code this in a navigation controller? I mean I know the subclassing and everything, but how would you call this method then or how would you program it?

Comment: UINavigationController has properties like `topViewController` and `visibleViewController`.  With a little research, one of these two will give you a reference to the right view controller (maybe both actually) that you need to call the method on whenever the keyboard appears.